# Custom Post Type by Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have two custom post types - office and professional. Each professional needs to be tied to an office. I've created a custom taxonomy, 'tax-location', applied it to both post types to tie them together.

I can view each single view of the ctp for office and professional with the templates single-office.php and single-professional.php as expected.

What I now need is to create a page that lists professionals by office on it's own page (think a subpage of the single-office view) and how to get that permalink dynamically. I've tried the taxonomy-$taxonomy-$slug.php template, but can't see to get it to work.

==== My Solution======

I ended up revisiting the taxonomy template solution. My taxonomy slug is tax-location, so I made a taxonomy-tax-location.php template.

To get the term link, I used the get_term_link() and passed the object through the first parameter, which echoes my link to a select field.

```
$career_terms = get_terms( 'tax-location' );
foreach ( $career_terms as $career_term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $career_term, 'tax-location')
    echo '<option value="' . $term_link . '">' . $career_term->name . '</option>';
}
```

From here I used javascript to bounce the user to the selected link that will take them to the taxonomy-tax-location.php template.

Once on the taxonomy-tax-location.php page, I wrote a function that passes the term slug of the queried page to a new WP_Query.

```
// in taxonomy-tax-location.php 
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
kg_get_careers($term->slug); 

// in functions.php
function kg_get_careers($term_slug = '') {

    $career_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'career',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax-location' => $term_slug
    );

    $career_posts = new WP_Query( $career_args );

    if ( $career_posts->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $career_posts->have_posts() ) : $career_posts->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'library/partials/part', 'careers-list' );
        endwhile;

    else: 

    echo 'No Content';

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

My solution is a bit verbose and I'm sure there's room for improvement, but it works for now.

Comment: So you need a template that applies to the "professional" custom post type but organizes all of them by office on one page? Or is it that you need a template that covers both "professional" as a custom post type but one page per "office"?

Comment: I need a template that lists all the professionals of an office. So if I click on the austin office, I want the user to be taken to page that lists the professionals for just that office.

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you try the taxonomy-$taxonomy-$slug.php? I have a feeling you may need to edit a template directly. In the meantime, this might help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plug-in [CPT-onomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-onomies/). It gives you the ability to set cpt office as a taxonomy for professionals.